# Operation failed due to an invalid (malformed or missing) API key

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-places-api

Using the Google code for IOS described at: [autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete)

At the first character entered by the user in the search box, an error occurs:

```
Error:  The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation failed due to an invalid (malformed or missing) API key. See the developer's guide (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/start) for information on creating and using an API key.
despite that calls to the API were successful:
GMS Services Key Valid:  true
GMS Services SDK version:  3.3.0
GMS Places Key Valid:  true
GMS Places SDK version:  3.3.0
```

Here's the trace of the application:

```
2019-08-17 16:46:52.056351-0400 GPDemo[345:15310] [DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialization successful
Entering AppDelegate.swift now...
Sending API key to Google Services and Places Client
GMS Services Key Valid:  true
GMS Services SDK version:  3.3.0
GMS Places Key Valid:  true
GMS Places SDK version:  3.3.0
Leaving AppDelegate.swift now...
warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information available.
Entering viewDidLoad now...
Leaving viewDidLoad now...
2019-08-17 16:51:54.281297-0400 GPDemo[345:15082] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2019-08-17 16:51:54.283666-0400 GPDemo[345:15082] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
Entering didUpdateAutocompletePredictions function now...
Leaving didUpdateAnyAutocompletePredictions function now...
2019-08-17 16:51:55.829602-0400 GPDemo[345:15082] [framework] CUIThemeStore: No theme registered with id=0
Entering didRequestAutocompletePredictions function now...
Leaving didRequestAutocompletePredictions function now...
Entering didUpdateAutocompletePredictions function now...
Leaving didUpdateAnyAutocompletePredictions function now...
Entering resultsContoller didFailAutocomplete function now...
Error:  The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation failed due to an invalid (malformed or missing) API key. See the developer's guide (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/start) for information on creating and using an API key.
Leaving resultsController didFailAutocomplete function now...
2019-08-17 16:54:13.293721-0400 GPDemo[345:15869] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x105e40a60] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-08-17 16:54:13.297185-0400 GPDemo[345:15869] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x105e40a60] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-08-17 16:54:13.299238-0400 GPDemo[345:15869] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2019-08-17 16:54:13.300271-0400 GPDemo[345:15869] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
```

Any help is appreciated.

Accessing the Map API with the same key works fine!

```
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  GPDemo
//



    import UIKit
    import GoogleMaps
    import GooglePlaces

    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

        var window: UIWindow?


        func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
        [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        print("Entering AppDelegate.swift now...")

        print("Sending API key to Google Services and Places Client")

        //// Maps API
        // JpDimoi "kiquoa-ios-places" key... 8/9/19
        let GMSServicesKeyValid = 
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("MY_API_KEY")
        // JpDimoi "kiquoa-ios" key...

        let GMSServicesSDKVer = GMSServices.sdkVersion()
        print("GMS Services Key Valid: ", GMSServicesKeyValid)
        print("GMS Services SDK version: ", GMSServicesSDKVer)

        //// Places API
        // JpDimoi "kiquoa-ios-places" key... 8/9/19
        let GMSPlacesKeyValid =      


        GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey(
         "MY_API_KEY")
        // JpDimoi "kiquoa-ios" key...

        let GMSPlacesSDKVer = GMSPlacesClient.sdkVersion()
        print("GMS Places Key Valid: ", GMSPlacesKeyValid)
        print("GMS Places SDK version: ", GMSPlacesSDKVer)

        print("Leaving AppDelegate.s`enter code here`wift now...")

        return true
        }

        func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
            // Sent when the application is about to move from active to 
            // inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary 
            // interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) 
            // or when the user quits the application and it begins the 
            // transition to the background state.
            // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and 
            // invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this 
            // method to pause the game.
        }

        func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
            // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, 
            // invalidate timers, and store enough application state 
    //information to 
            // restore your application to its current state in case it is 
    //terminated 
            // later.
            // If your application supports background execution, this method 
            // is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user 
    // quits.
        }

        func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
            // Called as part of the transition from the background to the 
            // active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on 
    // entering 
            // the background.
        }

        func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
            // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while 
            // the application was inactive. If the application was 
            // previously in the  
            // background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        }

        func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
            // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data 
            // if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        }


    }

    //  GPDemo ViewController.swift
    //
    //  Exact copy of code for results view controller
    //  when adding a searchBar to the top of the view
    //  Ref: https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete

    import UIKit
    import GooglePlaces

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        var resultsViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController?
        var searchController: UISearchController?
        var resultView: UITextView?

        override func viewDidLoad() {

            print("Entering viewDidLoad now...")
            super.viewDidLoad()

            resultsViewController = GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()
            resultsViewController?.delegate = self

            searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: 
            resultsViewController)
            searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = resultsViewController

            let subView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 65.0, width: 350.0, 
            height: 45.0))

            subView.addSubview((searchController?.searchBar)!)
            view.addSubview(subView)
            searchController?.searchBar.sizeToFit()
            searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

            // When UISearchController presents the results view, present it 
            // in
            // this view controller, not one further up the chain.
            definesPresentationContext = true

            print("Leaving viewDidLoad now...")
        }
    }

    // Handle the user's selection.
    extension ViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewControllerDelegate {
        func resultsController(_ resultsController: 
         GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
         didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
            searchController?.isActive = false
            print("Entering resultsController didAutocompleteWith place 
                  function now...")
            // Do something with the selected place.
            //print("Place name: \(place.name)")
            print("Place address: \(String(describing:     
            place.formattedAddress))")
            //print("Place attributions: \(place.attributions)")
            print("Leaving resultsController didAutocompleteWith place 
                 function now...")
        }

        func resultsController(_ resultsController: 
            GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
            didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error){
            // TODO: handle the error.
            print("Entering resultsContoller didFailAutocomplete function 
                  now...")
            print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
            print("Leaving resultsController didFailAutocomplete function 
                  now...")
        }

        // Turn the network activity indicator on and off again.
        func didRequestAutocompletePredictions(forResultsController 
            resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController) {
            print("Entering didRequestAutocompletePredictions function 
                  now...")
            UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
            print("Leaving didRequestAutocompletePredictions function 
                  now...")
        }

        func didUpdateAutocompletePredictions(forResultsController 
            resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController) {
            print("Entering didUpdateAutocompletePredictions function 
                  now...")
            UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            print("Leaving didUpdateAnyAutocompletePredictions function 
                  now...")

        }
    }
```

Expected the list of proposals to complete the address.

Comment: Have you enabled billing and the Places API on your project? Are you using a valid and properly restricted API key? If you try running the exact same code found in Google's guide with your API key, does the app still crash?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Please find below the answer to your questions:

Have you enabled billing and the Places API on your project?

>> not yet (I am in development phase with very few requests). If billing is the problem a specific error return code would be welcome.

Are you using a valid and properly restricted API key?

>> Yes restricted to "Maps SDK for IOS" and "Places SDK for IOS"

If you try running the exact same code found in Google's guide with your API key, does the app still crash?

>> app does not crash, it just gets an error described in the problem description

Comment: Thanks for your response. Okay so there are several problems at play here, let me write down a full answer for you.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error even after I enabled the Places API & generated the key as per the guide. But I didn't set the **billing account** for this API. Once I set that, the API was working properly. Just make sure you set up everything that's in the document
https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/start

Comment: Still dint work.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve enabled Places API and that helped me.
Do the following in the doc

https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/start

Answer (score 0):

This error you're getting is most likely specifically caused by your Cloud project configuration, not due to your own code implementation, especially considering that you get the same error when using Google's sample code (which fully works if you use a valid API key from a valid project).

First of all, **billing** must be enabled on your project for the Maps APIs to work at all, regardless of whether you're currently in a development phase or not.

Secondly, the old Places SDK for IOS is deprecated. To use the new Places SDK for IOS, the API that you need to enable and add to your API key's API restrictions is the **Places API**.

I recommend you go through Google's get started guides to properly set up your project and API key to use with the new Places SDK for IOS:
https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started

https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/start

Hope this helps.

Comment: Problem is fixed after adding "places api". What confused me is that with android I did not need this API to use autocomplete and I was expecting the same with IOS.

Comment: Sorry, sent went before ending. I just wanted to say your help has been highly appreciated.

Comment: Glad to hear, happy to have been of help. :)

Comment: The new Places SDK for mobile use Places API, both Android and IOS platforms. If you use Place Autocomplete from the new Places SDK for Android you'll also need Places API enabled. Both Android and IOS require this API as you've seen. ^^

Comment: Heya @Joaquin friendly reminder, if this answer solved or helped you solve your issue please [accept or upvote it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. The documentation doesn't fully explain how to active your API key. Here's what I figured out...

- Make sure you've got billing enabled on your Google Cloud Platform
- Go to your project on Google Cloud Platform
- Go to **API's & Services** => **Library**
- Search for **Places API**
- Click **Enable**
- Then follow the steps on here to restrict your API... 
  https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/get-api-key
- You can find your API under **API's & Services** => **Credentials**

That's what worked for me!